# Playwright trying to check if element is selected or not from the attached html

Tags: typescript, css-selectors, playwright

```
> <div id="ad-item-list" class="ad-item-list"> <div
> class="ad-search-item  " atdelegate="d185"> AMP </div> <div
> class="ad-search-item  " atdelegate="d186"> VLC </div> <div
> class="ad-search-item ad-selected " atdelegate="d187"> MMK </div> <div
> class="ad-search-item  " atdelegate="d188"> MED </div> <div
> class="ad-search-item  " atdelegate="d189"> LED </div> <div
> class="ad-search-item  " atdelegate="d190"> SED </div> <div
> class="ad-search-item  " atdelegate="d191"> DED </div> </div>
```

what css locator and playwright code can be used to get the value that is selected in this case MMK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await page.locator(".ad-search-item.ad-selected).toHaveText("MMK")`.

Which would assert that the selector has the given text.

Answer (score 1):

Complete code example to get selected value and assert it:

```
async function extractSelectedDisplayedValue(selectedOption) {
      return selectedOption.evaluate(sel => sel.options[sel.options.selectedIndex].textContent);
    }
    const selectedImageOption = page.locator('#imageSelect');
    expect(await extractSelectedDisplayedValue(selectedImageOption)).toBe('ExpectedValue');
```